# Solving differential equation - question about Step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the step that i cant get behind

$$
e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx} - e^{-x}y = \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}y)
$$

Here is what i thought
$$
- e^{-x} = \frac{d}{dx}e^{-x}
$$
so
$$
\frac{d}{dx} e^{-x}y+ \frac{d}{dx} e^{-x}y= \frac{d}{dx}(2e^{-x}y)
$$



edit: original post [Is the differential equation $y'=x+y$ separable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537629/is-the-differential-equation-y-xy-separable)

Comment: $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ this is the rule used

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thx :D

Comment: you're welcome...Dondo

Comment: Take the derivative of $e^{-x}y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx} - e^{-x}y = \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}y)$$
Is simply an application of:
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}y)=y\frac  {de^{-x}}{dx}+e^{-x}\dfrac {dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}y)=-ye^{-x}+e^{-x}\dfrac {dy}{dx}$$