# Separating the variables possible?

Tags: differential

Given the differential equation $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y+x$$

I am told this differential equation *is* separable. Meaning I need to rewrite the RHS into a product of two variables depending on y and x.

I've tried for some time now but I simply cannot figure out how this is separable. I'm able to solve it using the method of "integrating factor" and so I know the solution should be $$ y = Ce^x-x-1 $$

Any ideas?

Comment: It's clearly not separable. Possibly someone lied, possibly you misunderstood (maybe it was said that the DE can be converted to a separable equation or somethinglike that?)

Comment: It states: The equation is separable. Solve it using the learnt method (where you separate the variables). But I'm thinking there might be an error in the textbook (and I'm suppose to just use the integration factor method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps with $z:=y+x+1$,
$$ \frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}= \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+1=y+x+1=z.$$

Comment: I played around with it a little bit, but I couldn't get it working. I end up with $$dz=dy+dx$$. Then I want to expand $$z = y + x + 1$$ and end up with something wrong

Comment: I think the $+1$ is a bit artificial, proceeding with $z=x+y$ and ODE gives $\frac{dy}{dx}=z\implies dz=dx+dy=dx+zdx=(z+1)dx$ feels more intuitive.

Comment: I found this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537629/is-the-differential-equation-y-xy-separable

Here it states that is it NOT possible

Comment: It is not separable in $x,y$ but it is after a change of variables (namely it is separable in $x,z$).